# Count textarea signs correct php mb_strlen

Tags: php, entities, strlen

```
function countCharacterNoCK($contentVar, $maximumChars){

        $countThisString = strip_tags($contentVar);

        $umlaute = Array("/ä/","/ö/","/ü/","/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/","/ß/");
        $replace = Array("a","o","u","A","O","U","s");
        $countThisString1 = preg_replace($umlaute, $replace, $countThisString);

        $lenght = mb_strlen(html_entity_decode($countThisString1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

        if($lenght < $maximumChars+1){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return $lenght;
        }
}
```

This function doesn´t work as expected. Problem is: I´ve got a `<textarea>`, in which i can Press Enter.

```
<textarea name="testvalue">
12345 1234
1234512345
</textarea>
```

if i call my function `$test = countCharacterNoCK($_POST['testvalue'], 20);` it´ll return "22".

How to solve this? I´ve tried it with `strip_tags` but it didn´t solve my problem...I want the function to count like MS Office (Word), but can´t get this solved...any tipps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess that it is counting the invisible character of new lines '\n'.

you should try trim first that instead

```
$temporarystring =trim($countThisString1);
$lenght = mb_strlen(html_entity_decode($temporarystring, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Thanks, i just found out :) I think i´ll go with you solution. Thank you very much good sir.

Answer (score 0):

The whole day i searched, and now after i asked the question i found the solution:

```
$umlaute = Array("/ä/","/ö/","/ü/","/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/","/ß/",**"~[\r\n]+~"**);
$replace = Array("a","o","u","A","O","U","s",**""**);
```

Thanks for reading everyone